# Activity button in user profiles hidden or blocked by large hats

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

When users wear a large hat above the border of their profile picture, it sometimes hides the Activity tab button, which makes it impossible to visit their profile activity page directly.

Here are a couple of example using my own profile:

[image]
[image]

In the example on the left, the "Activity" button is completely hidden, and cannot be clicked.

In the example on the right, the "Activity" button is still partially visible, but it's impossible to click it.

When I visit other people's profiles wearing such hats, I can't go to their activity page directly. I have to use some alternative link (such as the links to view all the questions or answers).

Comment: [The same question was asked on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403735/how-can-i-see-a-milliners-activity).